# Recording numbers generated in a loop

Tags: python, loops, variables

I am creating a simple program to calculate how much of each component should be added to create a buffer of a desired final concentration of each component.  I want the user to be able to add as many components as necessary to the buffer.  For each component I have a loop that will tell the user how much of each component to add, but I can't seem to find a way to save each value as a variable and subtract it to the total buffer volume later.  In short, I want to record the value of each component after the loop runs, but I do not know how to achieve this.  Here is what I have so far

```
Buffer_Volume = input('What does the final volume of the buffer need to be, in mL? ')
Final_Volume = float(Buffer_Volume)

Component_Number = int(input('How many components does this buffer have? '))

x = 0
for  x in range(0, Component_Number):
    Stock = input('What is the molarity of the stock component? ')
    Stock_Molarity = float(Stock)

    Final = input('What does the final molarity of the component need to be? ')
    Final_Molarity = float(Final)

    #Volume = input('What does the final volume of the buffer need to be, in mL? ')
    #Final_Volume = float(Volume)

    Stock_Volume = (Final_Molarity * Final_Volume) / Stock_Molarity
    print('Add ' + str(round(Stock_Volume, 6)) + 'mL of stock component to the solution')

print('Add ' + str((Final_Volume - Stock_Volume)) + 'mL of water to the solution')
```

Comment: use a container, like a `list`

Comment: How do I add each value to the list?  I need the list to be infinitely expandable

Comment: ... `list` objects provide a variety of mutator methods. Likely, you simply want to `.append` to the list each iteration of your loop

Comment: I doubt you'll hit the limit on a `list`!

Comment: Okay appending a list seems like the way to go, but how do I actually do that?

Comment: `mylist.append(item_to_append)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is subtract the total stock volume from the final volume, all you need is an additional variable that you increment in the loop:

```
Buffer_Volume = input('What does the final volume of the buffer need to be, in mL? ')
Final_Volume = float(Buffer_Volume)

Component_Number = int(input('How many components does this buffer have? '))

x = 0
Stock_total = 0.
for  x in range(0, Component_Number):
    Stock = input('What is the molarity of the stock component? ')
    Stock_Molarity = float(Stock)

    Final = input('What does the final molarity of the component need to be? ')
    Final_Molarity = float(Final)

    #Volume = input('What does the final volume of the buffer need to be, in mL? ')
    #Final_Volume = float(Volume)

    Stock_Volume = (Final_Molarity * Final_Volume) / Stock_Molarity
    print('Add ' + str(round(Stock_Volume, 6)) + 'mL of stock component to the solution')

    Stock_total += Stock_Volume
print('Add ' + str((Final_Volume - Stock_total)) + 'mL of water to the solution')
```

If you need to do more with these values you have computed, simply store them in a list:

```
Buffer_Volume = input('What does the final volume of the buffer need to be, in mL? ')
Final_Volume = float(Buffer_Volume)

Component_Number = int(input('How many components does this buffer have? '))

x = 0
Stocks = []
for  x in range(0, Component_Number):
    Stock = input('What is the molarity of the stock component? ')
    Stock_Molarity = float(Stock)

    Final = input('What does the final molarity of the component need to be? ')
    Final_Molarity = float(Final)

    #Volume = input('What does the final volume of the buffer need to be, in mL? ')
    #Final_Volume = float(Volume)

    Stock_Volume = (Final_Molarity * Final_Volume) / Stock_Molarity
    print('Add ' + str(round(Stock_Volume, 6)) + 'mL of stock component to the solution')
    Stocks.append(Stock_Volume)

print('Add ' + str((Final_Volume - sum(Stocks))) + 'mL of water to the solution')
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that is exactly what I wanted to do!